# %E2%80%8B Appears in url .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, url, whitespace

I never experienced such issue, but it appears as part of route and if I manually enter route then the result is `404`.

If I copy from swagger `%E2%80%8B` appears.

How can I fix this issue?

.Net Core 2.1

http://localhost/functionCodes/%E2%80%8Btest - works

http://localhost/functionCodes/test - 404

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As per: [this chart](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)

`%E2%80%8B` is the code for a "ZERO-WIDTH SPACE" character.

It has probably been inserted without you noticing it somehow, you probably can't see it in your code, but it is here.

I recommend **completely removing the string** (including the surrounding quotes!) where the URL is defined and re-write it.

Since you use ASP.NET, this path may come from the name of an Action method in a Controller, but the solution is the same: remove completely the name of the `Test()` method, making sure you delete some space characters before that, and rewrite-it.

If you want to inspect this, you can probably use some advanced text editor or hexadecimal editor to view that it is actually in the source code.

There may be some Visual Studio extensions that would help you view these hidden characters as well.

Comment: I faced this issue while developing angular app as well, when I copied URL from swagger, this resolve it.. thanks!!!

Comment: The very same just happened to me now, but issue started when I copied the URL from swagger!! But typing it manually solved the problem.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I copied the address from a website page. The problem was that 3 characters %E2%80%8B were indeed copied and present in the address. VS just didn't display them. Intermediate copying to MS Word, followed by copying from there and pasting into VS helped to remove extra characters