# refit adds url encoded chars to the URI

Tags: c#, refit

Here's my method decorated with the refit post attribute

```
    [Post("/api/v2​/picking/{taskId}​/details/{id}/updateStatus?pickingStatus={pickingStatus}")]
    Task UpdateItemStatus(int taskId, int id, PickingStatus pickingStatus);
```

but here is how the request looks like with added url encoded chars

```
"/api/v2%E2%80%8B/picking/8637%E2%80%8B/details/27754/updateStatus?pickingStatus=10"
```

so I get an 404 error

Thanks for you insight.

Comment: Your string contains extra characters. Nothing wrong with refit. `"/api/v2​/picking/".Select(x => new { x, hex = ((int)x).ToString("x")})`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov which string in the attribute? or in the result generated by refit?

Comment: the answer is found here [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187010/e2808b-appears-in-url-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will be helpful, but i found this link https://www.programmersought.com/article/95491370698/ go to the **Rotary routing syntax** section. You can use ** to avoid url encoding.